# Cannot upload file from GCE (Compute Engine) to GCS in PHP by using gsutil

Tags: php, apache, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I try to upload file from GCE (Google Compute Engine) to GCS (Google Cloud Storage) by using gsutil in PHP.

```
     **exec("gsutil -m cp xxx.jpg  gs://a56/upload", $output, $return_var);**
```

I can upload file by using command (#gsutil -m cp xxx.jpg  gs://a56/upload), 
but it does not work in PHP.

The apache error log showed permission problem.

```
     **OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.config'**
```

I tried to avoid this problem by "chmod 777 /var/www" and add user "www-data" to "root" group, but I still got permission problem.

```
     **AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission
     **CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be transferred.
```

How can I solve this?
Or is there a better way to upload file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out by myself. 
I choose not to use gsutil to upload file due to permission issue.
Instead, I use google APIs Client Library (PHP) for service account. 
However, it has no existing example. I post my result on GitHub.

https://github.com/Brandon-Lin/google-cloud-storage/blob/master/upload_file_using_service_account.php

Make sure to apply service account. 
And download P12 key to your local machine. 
Then, you should apply "CLIENT ID" and "EMAIL ADDRESS" to my sample in GitHub.